# This page isn’t working after adding ajax jQuery with Laravel 10

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-10

I am a newbie to Ajax jQuery with Laravel. I am facing a problem that could not solve by me. expecting an expert's help.

**html:**

```
        <li>
            <a href="" onclick="routeTomystore()">
                <i class='bx bxs-shopping-bag-alt' ></i>
                <span class="text">My Store</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

**for base page:**

```
 <div class="con">
    @include('dashboard')
 </div>
```

**route:**

```
Route::get('/mystore', [routecontroller::class,'mystore'])->name('mystore');
```

**Ajax jQuery:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 routeTomystore(){
    event.preventDefault();
    const CSRF_TOCKEN=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({
    url: /mystore,
    // dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    // async: true,
    data: {
        CSRF_TOCKEN
    },
    success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            $("#con").html(data)
    },

    })
```

**controller:**

```
 public function mystore():View{
    $user = Registrationform::get();


    return view('message', compact('user'));
}
```

**Error showed in the browser:** 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

**Warn in vs code:**  WARN  PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\lv\lv10\storage\framework\views\d8110fcb222593c7306db2ca89d2a649.php on line 1.

WARN  PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 880640 bytes) in C:\lv\lv10\vendor\spatie\ignition\src\ErrorPage\ErrorPageViewModel.php on line 104.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** did you change?

Comment: Is there a `mystore()` method in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help

1. If you use `GET` method, you shouldn't send CSRF tokens in HTTP GET requests. This will make sure they are not directly available in the URL and they don’t leak in the Referrer header with other referrer information
2. Change your function in script

```
function routeTomystore(){
    $.ajax({
       url: /mystore,
       type: "GET",
       success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            $("#con").html(data)
       },
    })
```

3. Change your controller

```
 public function mystore():View{
    $user = Registrationform::get();

    return view('message', compact('user'))->render();
}
```

`Illuminate\View\View::render()` returns the string contents of the view.

And you can read more information about jquery ajax at here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/